# Filtering returned $.post data by class name

Tags: jquery

I have this html which i have returned after post:  http://jsfiddle.net/thiswolf/H8HTX/

I am only interested in the content in the div with `class one` and i am attempting to do that with

```
success: function(html){

               var ifilter = jQuery(html).find('.one').html();
               alert(ifilter);

  }
```

With this code,i am not able to strictly get what's under div with class one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First `add the html received in response to DOM` and then apply filters. Filter wont work on string. Remove the added html after you get the required html through find method.

```
success: function(html){             
           $('#someelementid').html(html); 
           var ifilter = $('#someelementid').find('.one').html();
           alert(ifilter);
           $('#someelementid').html(''); 
}
```